# Track files in submodules/subprojects

Tags: git

I have a subproject in the main project. And I want to track the files in the subproject, not just changes.

File/directory structure looks something like

mainproj:

- .git
- Test.java
- subproj

  - .git
  - Subtest.java

So if I push mainproj git ignores files in subproj. Adding Subtest.java explicitly gives an error

```
git add subproj/Subtest.java

fatal: Path 'subproj/Subtest.java' is in submodule 'subproj'
```

Is there an easy way to tell git to treat submodules as regular directories?

Comment: I found a solution. It's fake submodules. "git add subproj/" (with the slash) ignores .git in it and tracks its contents instead of adding a submodule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  Submodules are seperate git repositories and git knows they are tracked by a different repository and ignores them.  The parent repository only tracks the location of the submodule and what commit it is at.

To update changes to a submodule you need to go to that folder and create a branch (submodules, initially, are headless) make your changes and commit them to the submodule's repository -- pushing as needed.  Then, back in the main repository, a commit will need to be made to update the knowledge of what commit the submodule is now on.

Here is a good reference when working with submodules:  [Git Submodules:  Adding, Using, Removing, Updating](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/).